# null pointer exception in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

---

package common.ejdugedemo;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

```
public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws ExceptionInInitializerError
{
    return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}
```

}

*****************hibernate.cfg.xml**************************

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eattorney?characterEncoding=utf8</property>     
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Admin_answer"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Admin_question"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Audit_log"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Billing"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Custom_contract_billing_reports"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Dummyvariable"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Ejduge_login"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Entity_registration"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Gc_percentage"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Model_contract"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.User_master"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.User_registration"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Weightage"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Word_synonym"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Word_synonym_entity_wise"/>
        <mapping class="common.hibernate.bean.Word_synonym_temp"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

***********************Exception while build Session factory****************

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.hibernate.util.StringHelper.qualify(StringHelper.java:264)    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1283)
>     at
>   common.ejdugedemo.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:10)
>     at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:92)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: do you have any entity with OneToOne relationship ? I believe that is where the problem is. Can you add the code snippet here ?

Answer (score 0):

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eattorney?characterEncoding=utf8
        root
        root
        true
        update
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: is this additional info for the question or is this the answer ?